# Create pdf file in google drive using php from html

Tags: php, pdf, google-drive-api

I hava a html format and I want it to be created as pdf in my google drive

example this is my html format.

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>paragraph here... </p>
```

I want it to become a pdf in my google drive but I don't have any idea how to do it. this is a snip-it code of my php using google drive sdk.

```
....
//Then, insert the file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle( 'new_pdf' );
$file->setMimeType( 'application/pdf' );
$createdFile = $service->files->insert( $file, array(
    'data' => '<h1>Hello world!</h1><p>paragraph here... </p>',
    'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));
....
```

my question is that how can I put my html format to be applied in the pdf content?

I tried this one but in my google drive the `test.pdf` file is broken.

Comment: Use a html2pdf class to convert your data to pdf https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/

Comment: I don't think that I will be using html2pdf, I need the html format to be used in pdf created by google drive sdk

Comment: Should the mimetype be text/html ? Also did you add the other parameters to be passed when creating the google_drivefile? 
`$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }`

Comment: the mimetype is application/pdf, I would like in the content of the pdf file is in html format so that it will be easy to read..

Comment: `'mimeType' => 'text/plain'` change it to `'mimeType' => 'text/html'`